# How to use google map api in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I want to implement below code in react. Where can I use 'script' tag and how can I draw below map. Is there any built-in Library for showing route on map

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

   function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: I would try a library, https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

Comment: Please check my answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917552/issue-in-integrating-googlemaps-in-react-app/45920742#45920742.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the map component that is provided by primefaces primereact, it's functional and easily usable. Here is example taken from their: [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/gmap):

```
import {GMap} from 'primereact/components/gmap/GMap';

onMapReady(event) {
    this.setState({
        overlays: [
            new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 36.879466, lng: 30.667648}, title:"Konyaalti"}),
            new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: 36.883707, lng: 30.689216}, title:"Ataturk Park"}),
            new google.maps.Circle({center: {lat: 36.90707, lng: 30.56533}, fillColor: '#1976D2', fillOpacity: 0.35, strokeWeight: 1, radius: 1500}),
            new google.maps.Polyline({path: [{lat: 36.86149, lng: 30.63743},{lat: 36.86341, lng: 30.72463}], geodesic: true, strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 0.5, strokeWeight: 2})
        ]
    })
}

<GMap overlays={this.state.overlays} options={options} style={{width: '100%', minHeight: '320px'}} onMapReady={this.onMapReady}
                    onMapClick={this.onMapClick} onOverlayClick={this.onOverlayClick} onOverlayDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd} />
```